# VBA run time error

Tags: vba, ms-access

Run-time error on this code says 'Set Myrs=myqry.openrecordsheet() is the error, any ideas?

I have a button with this code:

Option Compare Database

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()

GetDataFromDate DateStart.Value, DateEnd.Value

End Sub
```

then I have vba with this:

```
Option Compare Database


Sub GetDataFromDate(dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date)

 Dim MyDb As Database, MyQry As QueryDef, MyRS  As Recordset
 Set MyDb = CurrentDb()
 Set MyQry = MyDb.CreateQueryDef("")

 ' Type a connect string using the appropriate values for your
 ' server.
 MyQry.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=PRDDLPA1;UID=purch_edi1;PWD=useedi;DBQ=PRDDLPA1;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;"

 ' Set the SQL query with Date Range passed to the sub as parameters
 MyQry.SQL = "SELECT NDC_CODE, SUM(INVOICE_QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY, SUM(INVOICE_QTY*UNIT_PRICE) AS EXT_DOLLAR_TOTAL, ITEM_NBR, TO_CHAR(EDI_INVOICE_DT, 'YYYYMM') " & _
 "FROM EDI_INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE" & _
 "WHERE AP_VENDOR_NBR IN('   242081') AND NOT((EDI_INVOICE_TYPE = 'C') AND (UNIT_PRICE = 0))" & _
 "AND (EDI_INVOICE_DT BETWEEN #" & dtStart & "# AND #" & dtEnd & "# " & _
 "AND LOCATION_NBR NOT IN('88017',' 88003',' 88010',' 88011',' 88018',' 88012',' 88008',' 88006',' 88001',' 88007',' 88009',' 88004',' 88019')" & _
" GROUP BY NDC_CODE, ITEM_NBR, TO_CHAR(EDI_INVOICE_DT, 'YYYYMM')"

 MyQry.ReturnsRecords = True
 Set MyRS = MyQry.OpenRecordset()

 MyRS.MoveFirst

 If Not MyRS.BOF Then

    While Not MyRS.EOF

        Debug.Print MyRS!TO_CHAR(EDI_INVOICE_DT)
        Debug.Print MyRS!NDC_CODE
        Debug.Print MyRS!TOTAL_QTY
        Debug.Print MyRS!EXT_DOLLAR_TOTAL
        Debug.Print MyRS!ITEM_NBR


        MyRS.MoveNext
    Wend


 End If

 MyQry.Close
 MyRS.Close
 MyDb.Close

End Sub
```

How can I fix this so that I can update my pass through query via my form with a new date range?

---

[From Comment] The Original Query looks like:

`SELECT NDC_CODE, SUM(INVOICE_QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY, SUM(INVOICE_QTY*UNIT_PRICE) AS EXT_DOLLAR_TOTAL, ITEM_NBR, TO_CHAR(EDI_INVOICE_DT, 'YYYYMM') FROM EDI_INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE WHERE AP_VENDOR_NBR IN(' 242081') AND NOT((EDI_INVOICE_TYPE = 'C') AND (UNIT_PRICE = 0)) AND (EDI_INVOICE_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('03/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('03/31/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) AND LOCATION_NBR NOT IN('88017',' 88003',' 88010',' 88011',' 88018',' 88012',' 88008',' 88006',' 88001',' 88007',' 88009',' 88004',' 88019') GROUP BY NDC_CODE, ITEM_NBR, TO_CHAR(EDI_INVOICE_DT, 'YYYYMM')`

Comment: What is the error message you receive? And have you double checked that your connection string is correct?

Comment: Run-time error '3146' and then it highlights "SET MyRS=MyQry.OpenRecordSet()   //yes connection string is correct.

Comment: Come on, it surely says something more than just '3146'?

Comment: Ohhh...haha sorry, yes, it says ODBC -- call failed, this is odd because it works when i run the query in the DB by itself...

Comment: Did you use the same user `purch_edi1` for that? Perhaps the table is located in another schema. Also, are there more verbose error messages in the `DBEngine.Errors` collection?

Comment: Access uses `#` characters to delimit date values.  The database you're connecting to is not Access.  So what characters does that database use to delimit date values?  (Probably not `#`)

Comment: The Original Query looks like: SELECT NDC_CODE, SUM(INVOICE_QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY, SUM(INVOICE_QTY*UNIT_PRICE) AS EXT_DOLLAR_TOTAL, ITEM_NBR, TO_CHAR(EDI_INVOICE_DT, 'YYYYMM') FROM EDI_INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE WHERE AP_VENDOR_NBR IN('   242081') AND NOT((EDI_INVOICE_TYPE = 'C') AND (UNIT_PRICE = 0)) AND (EDI_INVOICE_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('03/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('03/31/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) AND LOCATION_NBR NOT IN('88017',' 88003',' 88010',' 88011',' 88018',' 88012',' 88008',' 88006',' 88001',' 88007',' 88009',' 88004',' 88019') GROUP BY NDC_CODE, ITEM_NBR, TO_CHAR(EDI_INVOICE_DT, 'YYYYMM')

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you secretly connect to an Oracle database. Then date values must be formatted as *yyyy-mm-dd* string expressions:

```
"AND (EDI_INVOICE_DT BETWEEN '" & Format(dtStart, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND '" & Format(dtEnd, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' " & _
```

or try the other date format:

```
"AND (EDI_INVOICE_DT BETWEEN '" & Format(dtStart, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "' AND '" & Format(dtEnd, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "' " & _
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this but I still get the same error. I'm new to VBA, what does " Set MyRS = MyQry.OpenRecordset()" mean?

Comment: It means to open a recordset using MyQry.

Comment: so now I have the error 'method or data member not found'

Comment: Try with a very basic select query like "SELECT NDC_CODE FROM EDI_INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE" and modify code until success. Then build up this query step by step, correcting errors you may encounter before proceeding with the next step.